# What is the sum of the series?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

How to find the sum of the series $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {x^{3^n}+(x^{3^n})^2} {1-x^{3^{n+1}}}$$ under the assumptions $x >0,\,x\neq 1,$ in a closed form?

Comment: Hint: $$\frac{u+u^2}{1-u^3} = \frac{1}{1-u} - \frac{1}{1-u^3}$$

Comment: @achille hui:Can you explain the next step?

Comment: Substitute $x^{3^n}$ for $u$ and you get a telescoping series.

Comment: @achillehui how did you get to the RHS?

Comment: Unfortunately, the command of Maple $$sum(1/(1-x^{3^n}), n = 0 .. infinity) $$ produces nothing. This is not a telescoping series. I am waiting for a serious answer.

Comment: $\frac{1}{1-x}= 1+x+x^2+x^3+...$

Comment: @eccstartup:So what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $\displaystyle \frac{u+u^2}{1-u^3} = \frac{1}{1-u} - \frac{1}{1-u^3}$,
$$\sum_{n=0}^N \frac {x^{3^n}+(x^{3^n})^2} {1-x^{3^{n+1}}}
= \sum_{n=0}^N \left( \frac{1}{1-x^{3^{n}}} - \frac{1}{1-x^{3^{n+1}}}\right)
=\frac{1}{1-x^{3^0}} - \frac{1}{1-x^{3^{N+1}}}
$$
This implies
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {x^{3^n}+(x^{3^n})^2} {1-x^{3^{n+1}}} = \frac{1}{1-x} - \lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{1-x^{3^{N+1}}}
= \frac{1}{1-x} - 
\begin{cases}
1, & |x| < 1\\
\frac12 & x = -1\\
\text{undefined}, & x = 1\\
0, & |x| > 1\\
\end{cases}$$

Comment: In general, I find your answer right. If $x=-1$ , then the numerator $x^{3^n}+(x^{3^n})^2$ equals zero for each natural $n$. I think $\mathbb{N}:=\{1,2,\dots\}.$

Comment: can you write me how did you get to the RHS?

Comment: @OfirAttia $$u + u^2 = 1 + u + u^2 - 1 = \frac{1-u^3}{1-u} - 1$$ The key is people are not very ingenious in creating new questions/exercises. If a series looks incredibly complicated but yet expected to be solvable, then the person creating the question is probably using some tricks. Telescoping series is one of the most common choices. If you suspect the series is a telescoping series in disguise, then based on the pattern in the expression, there are usually not many things one could try....